# Change format view data export module

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I want change format display [View Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) from table to unformatted list

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to create a view page
- Display & filter those information which you want to export
- Click on **+Add** & select Data Export
- Under format you get an option to change to unformatted list
- Save & check

For detailed description click on the [**LINK**](https://www.drupal.org/node/1820452).

Comment: When add (data export) alway show table format

Comment: I want to create a template for the "data export" but do not know the custom field

Comment: Have you check that Link which I have mentioned above.

Comment: You have asked to change the format of Views Data Export. What you are asking i.e. "custom field" ? If this is a new question then ask as new question don't mix two questions in one.